# Detect dismissal of the keyboard (by back button) in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard, focus

I have a set of `EditText` fields generated by a for loop. Each time that field is edited, I need to run some calculations and update other text fields (think excel spreadsheet sums).

My logic is working, and I even have it set up to replace the last field's down focus change to the first field (to avoid the "Done" button showing on the keyboard).

However, if the user presses the Back button to dismiss the keyboard, the focus is not changed and the calculations are not done. The entered number is different but now the totals are wrong. I can't find where to detect when the keyboard is dismissed so I can work around this.

What I have now:

```
final EditText etWeight = new EditText(this);
etWeight.setText("initWt");
etWeight.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
etWeight.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        //code to update after weight is changed
    }
));
llWeightRow.addView(etWeight);
```

I have also tried putting this code in `setOnEditorActionListener`, `setOnClickListener`, and `setOnKeyListener`.

Aside from some of these not working as expected, none of them appear to trigger if the back button is pressed to dismiss the keyboard. I have searched online but only came up with suggestions on how to manually hide the keyboard with my own button; I can't seem to find anything concerning the back button on the tablet itself.

How can I detect that the keyboard has been dismissed so I can force a focus change (or just re-run the calculation code)?

**Update**:
Not marking this as answered because this doesn't answer this specific question, but I currently am producing my desired results (other fields always updated) by switching to a `onTextChanged` method. Now the values are updated whenever any text inside the `EditText` is changed.

```
etWeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        //calc and update code
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to override onBackPressed? You can make your manipulations with focus there.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Make needed preparations here
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Tried that (put "getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();" in there). If I change a value and press the back button, the keyboard is dismissed but the EditText retains focus. If I then press the back button again, the activity is dismissed, but I can see the field lose focus and my numbers update just before the activity goes away. It doesn't look like onBackPressed is called if the back button just dismisses the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ActivityName.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Software Keyboard was shown");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Software Keyboard was not shown");
        }
```

Comment: but where would I call that from? My problem isn't that I can't figure out how to detect whether the keyboard is present, its that I can't find the appropriate "onWhatever" that fires when the back button is pressed to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: first back button press is not the only way to dismiss your keyboard.so focus on the visibility of the keyboard fire  events related to that not with the back button and you can do it inside onCreate  read about android:imeOptions